# Differences when scaling images

Tags: c#, graphics, drawimage

I need to scale image and I have problem with using graphics to do it. I use DrawImage, I pass original image, new Location (0, 0), and new size. The result image is scaled but its upper and left edge is transparent. Anyone know why?
My code:

```
Rectangle DstRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int) (CurrentImage.ImgBM.Width * Zoom), (int) (CurrentImage.ImgBM.Height * Zoom));
//ReducedBM = new Bitmap((int)(CurrentImage.ImgBM.Width * Zoom), (int)(CurrentImage.ImgBM.Height * Zoom));
ReducedBM = new Bitmap(CurrentImage.ImgBM, DstRec.Width, DstRec.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(ReducedBM);
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;
//g.DrawImage(CurrentImage.ImgBM, 0, 0, (int)(CurrentImage.ImgBM.Width * Zoom), (int)(CurrentImage.ImgBM.Height * Zoom));
g.DrawImage(CurrentImage.ImgBM, DstRec);
g.Dispose();
```

Comment: If you are using the constructor overload that does all the scaling, why draw the image again? The scaling should be done with the 2nd line, no? - Or use the DrawImage overload with two Rectangles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is a problem with this line:

```
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;
```

change it to this one.

```
g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
```

Comment: It didn't change anytinhg, but when I use NearestNeighbor, it is OK, but image is ugly

Comment: Now we now that it is interpolation problem, but still dont't know why. Default interpolation is OK too.

Comment: Look this article: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/28/preventing-ghost-borders-when-resizing-images-with-system-drawing